# mysql query to calculate values local to Cartesian products of logical groups of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query to process a single table that looks like this:

```
record_id   item_id   part_id   part_length
-----------  -------   --------  ------------
     1         0         0         123.12
     2         0         0         123.09
     3         0         1         231.24
     4         0         1         239.14
     5         1         0          45.91
     6         1         0          46.12
     7         1         1          62.24
     8         1         1          59.40
```

which is basically a table of inaccurate length measurements of some parts of some items recorded multiple times (not twice, actually each part has 100s of measurements). With a single select, I want to get a result like this:

```
record_id   item_id   part_id   unit      part_length_ratio
-----------  -------   --------  -----     ----------------
     1         0         0        1       123.12 / 231.24 
     2         0         0        1       123.09 / 239.14 
     3         0         1        0       231.24 / 123.12
     4         0         1        0       239.14 / 123.09
     5         1         0        1        45.91 /  62.24
     6         1         0        1        46.12 /  59.40
     7         1         1        0        62.24 /  45.91
     8         1         1        0        59.40 /  46.12
```

which is basically selecting each part of an item as the unit and calculates the ratio of the length of other parts of the same item to this unit while matching the measurement times. I wrote a script which computes this kind of table but would like to do it with sql. I can understand if you fail to understand the question :)

```
for each item i
  for each part unit of i
     for each part other of i
        if unit != other
           print i.id other.part_id unit.part_id other.length / unit.length
```

Comment: You probably missing something. For [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), |N✕M| = |N|✕|M|. Here the "result" has the same number of rows as the "original". This *feeling* is confirmed by the fact that you only have the ratio "123.12/231.24" and "123.09/239.14", but for strange reason not "123.12/239.14" nor "123.09/231.24". Whereas the other columns (except id) as indistinguishable. Is it on purpose? In that case, you will have to explain clearly (formula, pseudo-code) on which basis you match pair of lines.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, thanks. Added some pseudo code to clarify. I agree, it is not Cartesian product.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: the for loops don't use the same columns names as in your example table. Anyway, even trying hard, I doesn't explain why you have "123.12 / 231.24" *but not* "123.12 / 239.14". Except for the ID, the lines ID3 and ID4 are *indistinguishable*. If this is the problem, please remember that tables are *unordered set* of rows. There is no "odd" and "even" lines. Maybe do you require to match somehow according the "ID" (which is probably *not* a good idea)?

Comment: There is no "123.12 / 239.14" because 123.12 is the first sample for part 0 and 239 is the second sample for part 1. I'm trying to pair lengths from same samples. Not based on even/odd but based on the sequence numbers relative to their corresponding parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, tables are *unordered sets*: there is no *first* or *second* row...

... unless if you want to use the `id` column to explicitly order the rows.

However, can you guarantee that there will always be (exactly) two samples for each case and that the "lower ID" always match the first sample? This appears to be quite fragile as in real-life, there will probably have cases where a test will be performed twice or a test will be missing or done "late". Not mentioning concurrent access to your DB.

Can't you simply add a "sample number" column?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will add the sample id column. I was trying with `id - min(id)` with inner joins to get the sample id but it doesn't look good anyway.